# Android widget rendering error

Tags: java, android, rendering

How can I fix it? I created the project and bam, instant error without touching any code. Any fixing method is appreciated. I have tried sync, clean code, clean cache. None of these methods work.

```
enter code here java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor471.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:250)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Your problem is with the Android Studio preview, not necessarily with your code. At best, if you provide the XML of the layout that you are trying to edit, we might be able to make some suggestions of changes to that XML to make the editor behave better.

Comment: you need to provide us your widget's XMLs and Java class